# PHP Inserting JSON Data into MySQL database from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have an Android app that sends data via HTTP POST method to a PHP script and am trying to parse the data to store into a MySQL. The Android app was not written by me but I have access to the source code which I have included below; it sends the data packed as a JSON array.  My PHP script right now attempts to put the data both into a text file and into a MySQL DB:

```
<?php

   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbname","dbpassword","table");
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL DB: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

   $filename = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."jsontest.txt";

   $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
   $data = json_decode($postdata, true);


   //if (array_key_exists('records', $data) && is_array($data['records'])) {
   //above if loop threw warning "array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array,  null given"

   if (is_array($data['records'])) {
      foreach ($data['records'] as $record) {
        $name = $record['name'];
        $value = $record['value'];
    $event = $record['event'];
        $timestamp = $record['timestamp'];

        file_put_contents($filename, "$name -> $value with event: $event at $timestamp\n", FILE_APPEND);
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `Driving Data`(`Name`, `Value`, `Event`, `Timestamp`) VALUES ($name, $value, $event, $timestamp)");
      }
   }

   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The text file prints out all of the data like I tell it to. The database, however, is never updated at all. The database is set up as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Driving Data` (
 `Name` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
 `Value` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 `Event` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is how an example of the JSON data looks:

```
{"records":[{"name":"accelerator_pedal_position","value":15.400001,"timestamp":1367598908.278000},{"name":"engine_speed","value":1716.0,"timestamp":1367598908.285000},{"name":"vehicle_speed","value":32.040001,"timestamp":1367598908.290000},{"name":"brake_pedal_status","value":false,"timestamp":1367598908.293000},{"name":"fuel_consumed_since_restart","value":0.147325,"timestamp":1367598908.301000},{"name":"transmission_gear_position","value":"third","timestamp":1367598908.304000},{"name":"steering_wheel_angle","value":-2.3733,"timestamp":1367598908.307000},{"name":"fuel_consumed_since_restart","value":0.14745,"timestamp":1367598908.314000},{"name":"transmission_gear_position","value":"third","timestamp":1367598908.317000},{"name":"door_status","value":"driver","event":false,"timestamp":1367598908.320000},{"name":"door_status","value":"passenger","event":false,"timestamp":1367598908.326000},{"name":"door_status","value":"rear_left","event":false,"timestamp":1367598908.329000},{"name":"door_status","value":"rear_right","event":false,"timestamp":1367598908.331000},{"name":"odometer","value":0.0,"timestamp":1367598908.338000},{"name":"high_beam_status","value":false,"timestamp":1367598908.341000},{"name":"steering_wheel_angle","value":-2.3733,"timestamp":1367598908.343000},{"name":"engine_speed","value":1716.0,"timestamp":1367598908.351000},{"name":"powertrain_torque","value":74.0,"timestamp":1367598908.358000},{"name":"accelerator_pedal_position","value":12.1,"timestamp":1367598908.364000},{"name":"latitude","value":42.293911,"timestamp":1367598908.367000},{"name":"longitude","value":-83.238762,"timestamp":1367598908.376000},{"name":"engine_speed","value":1718.0,"timestamp":1367598908.380000},{"name":"vehicle_speed","value":32.200001,"timestamp":1367598908.382000},{"name":"brake_pedal_status","value":false,"timestamp":1367598908.391000},{"name":"transmission_gear_position","value":"third","timestamp":1367598908.393000}]}
```

So I am relatively new to PHP, and I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is (i.e. why the database is not being updated with these values but it can still write them out to a text file.  For reference, below is the Android code used to send the data to the web server (I cannot change this):

```
public class UploaderSink extends ContextualVehicleDataSink {
private final static String TAG = "UploaderSink";
private final static int UPLOAD_BATCH_SIZE = 25;
private final static int MAXIMUM_QUEUED_RECORDS = 5000;
private final static int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 5000;

private URI mUri;
private BlockingQueue<String> mRecordQueue =
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(MAXIMUM_QUEUED_RECORDS);
private Lock mQueueLock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition mRecordsQueued = mQueueLock.newCondition();
private UploaderThread mUploader = new UploaderThread();

/**
 * Initialize and start a new UploaderSink immediately.
 *
 * @param uri the URI to send HTTP POST requests to with the JSON data.
 */
public UploaderSink(Context context, URI uri) {
    super(context);
    mUri = uri;
}

public UploaderSink(Context context, String path) throws DataSinkException {
    this(context, uriFromString(path));
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    super.stop();
    mUploader.done();
}

public boolean receive(RawMeasurement measurement) {
    String data = measurement.serialize(true);
    mRecordQueue.offer(data);
    if(mRecordQueue.size() >= UPLOAD_BATCH_SIZE) {
        mQueueLock.lock();
        mRecordsQueued.signal();
        mQueueLock.unlock();
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns true if the path is not null and if it is a valid URI.
 *
 * @param path a URI to validate
 * @return true if path is a valid URI.
 *
 */
public static boolean validatePath(String path) {
    if(path == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Uploading path not set (it's " + path + ")");
        return false;
    }

    try {
        uriFromString(path);
        return true;
    } catch(DataSinkException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return Objects.toStringHelper(this)
        .add("uri", mUri)
        .add("queuedRecords", mRecordQueue.size())
        .toString();
}

private static URI uriFromString(String path) throws DataSinkException {
    try {
        return new URI(path);
    } catch(java.net.URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new UploaderException(
            "Uploading path in wrong format -- expected: ip:port");
    }
}

private static class UploaderException extends DataSinkException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7436279598279767619L;

    public UploaderException() { }

    public UploaderException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

private class UploaderThread extends Thread {
    private boolean mRunning = true;

    public UploaderThread() {
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(mRunning) {
            try {
                ArrayList<String> records = getRecords();
                String data = constructRequestData(records);
                HttpPost request = constructRequest(data);
                makeRequest(request);
            } catch(UploaderException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Problem uploading the record", e);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Uploader was interrupted", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void done() {
        mRunning = false;
    }

    private String constructRequestData(ArrayList<String> records)
            throws UploaderException {
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter(512);
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
        try {
            JsonGenerator gen = jsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(buffer);

            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeArrayFieldStart("records");
            Iterator<String> recordIterator = records.iterator();
            while(recordIterator.hasNext()) {
                gen.writeRaw(recordIterator.next());
                if(recordIterator.hasNext()) {
                    gen.writeRaw(",");
                }
            }
            gen.writeEndArray();
            gen.writeEndObject();

            gen.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to encode all data to JSON -- " +
                    "message may be incomplete", e);
            throw new UploaderException();
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private HttpPost constructRequest(String data)
            throws UploaderException {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(mUri);
        try {
            ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(
                    data.getBytes("UTF8"));
            entity.setContentEncoding(
                    new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));
            request.setEntity(entity);
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Couldn't encode records for uploading", e);
            throw new UploaderException();
        }
        return request;
    }

    private void makeRequest(HttpPost request) throws InterruptedException {
        HttpParams parameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(parameters, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(parameters, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(parameters);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Got unxpected status code: " + statusCode);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Problem uploading the record", e);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e2) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Uploader interrupted after an error", e2);
                throw e2;
            }
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getRecords() throws InterruptedException {
        mQueueLock.lock();
        if(mRecordQueue.isEmpty()) {
            // the queue is already thread safe, but we use this lock to get
            // a condition variable we can use to signal when a batch has
            // been queued.
            mRecordsQueued.await();
        }

        ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
        mRecordQueue.drainTo(records, UPLOAD_BATCH_SIZE);

        mQueueLock.unlock();
        return records;
    }
}
```

Comment: The sending code shouldn't be relevant, only the receiving code and input data. Please post your query string in the form it's run with all input variables inserted.

Comment: You should add some error checking for mysqli_query, it will help you debug the issue. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also mention your data type of your table columns

Comment: Also, there's no quotation in your insert statement for the values. And it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Just added the data types for the MySQL columns into the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Converting unix timestamp to mysql timestamp

```
if (is_array($data['records'])) {
  foreach ($data['records'] as $record) {
    $name = $record['name'];
    $value = $record['value'];
$event = $record['event'];
    $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$record['timestamp']);

    file_put_contents($filename, "$name -> $value with event: $event at $timestamp\n", FILE_APPEND);
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `Driving Data`(`Name`, `Value`, `Event`, `Timestamp`) VALUES ($n

ame, $value, $event, $timestamp)");
      }
   }
```

Comment: This was causing me the problem, the timestamp was not in the correct format. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think your SQL syntax is wrong. Look at this line:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `Driving Data`(`Name`, `Value`, `Event`, `Timestamp`) VALUES ($name, $value, $event, $timestamp)");
```

If any variable ($name for example) has spaces, your SQL will be like this:

```
INSERT INTO `Driving Data`(`Name`, `Value`, `Event`, `Timestamp`) VALUES (Name with spaces, ...)
```

but it should be between single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `Driving Data`(`Name`, `Value`, `Event`, `Timestamp`) VALUES ('Name with spaces', ...)
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it's the source of your problem. I assume that's the error line because, as you say, the text file is created (so the file_put_contents before is running ok).

Also, why aren't you using some kind of "ID" for your inserted rows? I would add an auto-incrementable "id" column as the primary key.

Comment: You could use if (!mysqli_query($con, ...)) die("SQL error: " . mysqli_error($con)); to check for SQL errors

Answer (score 0):

Right now, just looking at your code you have VALUES written twice in the INSERT command.

It currently appears as: `...`Timestamp`) VALUES VALUES ($name,...`

Remove the second occurance of VALUES and see if it works. It never threw an error message?

Comment: Oh, I think I accidentally somehow copied another "VALUES" when I was putting the code in the post, that is not actually in the code I am testing (so is not causing a problem). I removed it from the post

Comment: Ahh, okay. You might need to add single quotes before and after the variables, unless it is a number. Like so: VALUES ('$name', '$value', '$event', '$timestamp')

I don't believe floats need to be quoted, but test it out and remove the quotes around them if they don't.

Comment: If the data is getting written to file, then it's definitely not an Android problem. Did you try just inserting the value of 1 instead of the variables to see if the query is even talking to the database for debugging purposes? Perhaps add die() to the tail end directly after the mysqli_query function. Like so: mysqli_query() or die('Query did not work.'); And see if the did not work statement comes back. Perhaps this link will help as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304894/having-a-problem-getting-mysqli-query-to-execute